# PHP function. Use function from another function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, post

I have a problem with a php function, or i need to know how (or if work) can use:

```
<?php
$_POST["search"] = substr($_POST["search"], -11);
echo $_POST["search"]
?>
```

I want to use results of search echo $_POST['search'] here: (into da other php function.

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents("http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=".$HERE);
parse_str($content, $ytarr);
echo $ytarr['title'];
?>
```

Where is .$HERE  i want to put searh result function. If someone submit a post INWR29242jr (example), with first code, in 2nd code i want to have exactly 1st result.

I hope I was clear enough. Im amateur, but i want to learn.
Thank you!

Comment: `$content = file_get_contents("http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=" . substr($_POST["search"], -11))`?

Comment: Work. Thank you so much. It was easy. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `$HERE` with result returned by `substr`:

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=" . substr($_POST["search"], -11))
```